# Как определятся "новизна" участника?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, профиль-участника, новые-участники

Встретил такого участника https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300779/user300779
Согласно данных профиля, этот участник зарегистрировался 7 месяцев назад, однако, у него стоит флаг, что это новый участник

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Qweriy а зачем тут красная метка вообще? Это ж не дефект, требующий отметить исход проблемы.

Comment: @älёxölüt ну, изначальный посыл вопроса был именно как дефект. В целом красная метка вреда не несёт. как по мне.

Comment: @Suvitruf больше меток, больше знаков по меткам :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/260198)

> The new indicator works by the age of a user's first visible post

Показ плашки зависит от того, когда было опубликовано первое видимое сообщение, а не от даты регистрации.